# List files, count number of OK and NOK and sort by date

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I have a database with 3 columns. One that has a file path called **path**, one with the value OK or NOK called **status** and another with the date and time called **time**.

```
Path        Status      Date 
/var/log    200         2016-10-20
/etc/rc.d   404         2016-10-21
/etc/rc.d   200         2016-10-21
```

So I am trying to sort by paths that are the same but show a count of how many times it was successful and not successful by date and path.

I tried something like this but it's giving me the total number of errors from the entire database and not those that happen on the given day.

```
select to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date, 
       (SELECT count(status) from  log where status like '404%') as error,
       (SELECT count(status) from log where status like '200%') as success 
from log group by date, error, success limit 10;


  date      | error | success 
------------+-------+---------
 2016-07-01 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-02 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-03 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-04 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-05 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-06 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-07 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-08 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-09 | 12908 | 1664827
 2016-07-10 | 12908 | 1664827
 (10 rows)
```

Comment: Running "select path, status, count(status), to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date from log group by path, status, date;" gives me the correct counts but i get one entry for each date, one that shows how many successes and how many failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sumif like in excel:

```
SELECT 
    date,
    path,
    SUM(IF(status like '200%', 1, 0)) as success,
    SUM(IF(status like '404%', 1, 0)) as error
FROM log
GROUP BY date, path;
```